# Are goldenrod cultivars manageable or troublesome?

Tags: perennials

We have a tough dry spot in the garden (USDA zone 4) about 2' x 5' where a goldenrod cultivar would go nicely. The [native species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidago_canadensis), although attractive, has a tendency to seed freely and be almost impossible to remove.

Are the cultivars more manageable, or do they seed freely and propagate by rhizomatous roots like the native species?

Comment: Two years later the clumping variety are very nicely behaved.  They flower reliably, do not sow seed all over the place and stay in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on the exact variety you choose, some are "clump forming", while others are more like the [native species you mentioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidago_canadensis) -- will naturalise.

Varieties that naturalise can be controlled (somewhat) by dividing the plant every 2 or 3 years.

**Some "clump forming" varieties:**

- [Blue stem goldenrod - *Solidago caesia*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=Y370)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago* 'Early Bird'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=A281)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago* 'Goldkind' Golden Baby](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=F600)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago hispida*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=K500)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago* 'Leraft'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=B848)

**Some "will naturalise" varieties:**

- [Goldenrod - *Solidago* 'Crown of Rays'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=P970)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago* 'Gold Spangles'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=W560)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago rigida*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=F610)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago speciosa*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=G690)
- [Goldenrod - *Solidago sphacelata* 'Golden Fleece'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=F620)

All of the above plants are approved for [UDSA hardiness zone 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardiness_zone#USDA_Hardiness_Zones).